# Sandbox copy: does it copy the data?

Tags: sandbox, sandbox-refresh

Does the new Summer '16 Sandbox copy feature also copy the data ?

Answer (score 2):

As per Salesforce docs

> You can now create a sandbox by cloning an existing sandbox rather
>   than using your production org as your source. Save time by populating
>   any type of sandbox with a previously chosen set of data and metadata.
>   (Sandbox templates, which serve a similar purpose, are available only
>   for Full or Partial Copy sandboxes.) Sandbox-to-sandbox cloning
>   facilitates iterative development, allowing you to freeze development
>   in one sandbox and pick up where you left off in a new one. This
>   feature is available in both Lightning Experience and Salesforce
>   Classic.

So answer is yes you can move data in full copy and partial copy SB same concept we use in sandbox creation.

[Reference](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_deployment_sandbox_to_sandbox.htm)

Comment: Even, If you only need to create 'sample' info for test your news functionalities, you can do an Apex Class for Sandbox since Spring'16

https://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_deployment_sandbox_postcopy_script.htm

Answer (score 2):

As per Salesforce documentation "*When you clone a sandbox, all its data and metadata are copied into the new sandbox.*".

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=data_sandbox_create.htm